# Eclipse: compare editor colors were changed by a plugin, how can I reset these?

Tags: eclipse

A plugin I installed recently (Aptana Studio) modified all sorts of preference settings, and uninstalling the plugin did not get me back to where I was before so I have to revert the settings by hand.  One of these is the colors used for the changed text in the compare editor(s).  I don't see how I can modify these preferences via the "Colors and Fonts" settings, perhaps because it's not clear which color settings I need to modify.

Attached is a screenshot showing how things currently look, i.e. black and dark grey are used to highlight changed sections of Java code, and I want to have something which is easier to read (it used to be that these were light colors which worked well with my other color settings).

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone comment as to which color settings I should modify?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same problem using Aptana Studio 3. It messed up my Eclipse Preferences. For some reason you cannot reset the background color for the text compare window under Window->Preferences.

Anyway, do the following to fix it:

Go into your working directory you are using when starting Eclipse, lets say its /home/src
In /home/src there is a ".metadata" folder. Then go into the ".plugins" folder. Then "org.eclipse.core.runtime". Then ".settings". Now there should be file called "org.eclipse.compare.prefs". Open it, find the line starting with "AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background". This one is some sort of general global background color for TextEditors from type AbstractTextEditor. Change it to your needs using RGB color values. Save it. Restart Eclipse. Worked for me.

Comment: Helped me a lot to cleanup garbage after Aptana Studio

Comment: Setting it to `AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background=250,250,250` worked great for me. Thanks

Comment: AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background=250,250,250 helped me too, thanks

Comment: It went a bit funny on me again recently so I also needed to add `AbstractTextEditor.Color.Foreground=0,0,0`as well as the `AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background=250,250,250` I mentioned in the comment above

Comment: Another thing that went wrong was my current line colour. Its easier for me to just paste in my file in another answer below (its to big for a comment)

Comment: I just deleted the contents of the file and i got the eclipse defaults back.

Answer (score 17):

Go to Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Themes and change to Eclipse.

Comment: Better to do Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details and uninstall that piece of crap Aptana that hosed my Eclipse installation.

Comment: This may be effective as long as you still have Aptana Studio installed. In my case, I unwittingly gave myself a bigger headache because I reinstalled Eclipse Indigo but never tried to uninstall the Aptana Studio components beforehand. So those settings were left in org.eclipse.compare.prefs to confound me. (Until I found this post.) :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a Text Compare category in Colors and Fonts, where I found the settings I believe were changed. I describe my colors here:

Conflicting change color: 255, 0, 0 (RGB red)
Incoming change color: 0, 0, 255 (RGB blue)
Outgoing change color: 0, 0, 0 (RGB black)
Resolved change color: 0, 255, 0 (RGB green)

Comment: Yes I have the same settings for those colors, and since they're not black or grey I assumed that these were not the color settings in play.

Comment: Sadly I don't have any concrete idea left. Maybe you could try to export your preferences (File/Export/Preferences) from the Aptana-modified one and from a clean workspace (preferences are workspace related), and do a file-level diff to find what is changed - but this way seems hard because as you cannot export only the color settings...

Answer (score 2):

Under your "Colors and Fonts" setting, did you check the settings under the "Text Compare" node? There, I have options for incoming, outgoing, resolved and conflicted colors. You can hit 'reset' on all of those to see if those are in fact the settings.

Comment: Yes I have looked into this section, but none of the colors there are black or grey (the offending colors I'm trying to reset), and I'm afraid to hit reset since it will not only reset these but also every other color and font setting I've made so far.

Comment: I am having the same issue after installing Appcelerator (titanium). were you manage to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: I tried the very same thing you suggested, but to no avail. It really does seem like the surest solution is to remove org.eclipse.compare.prefs and start fresh with the colors.

I noticed that this file contained a lot of lines with settings ending in "SystemDefault=false". This may be the root of the problem, but I'm not sure. Once I removed (well, renamed) that file and saw the default colors, I was happy and I let it be.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a continuation of my comments to the accepted answer.

Its just easier to include my entire `org.eclipse.compare.prefs` file here. The colours are not great but they work. Its then easier for you to modify them yourself to an appealing colour palette.

```
AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background.SystemDefault=false
AbstractTextEditor.Color.Foreground.SystemDefault=false
AbstractTextEditor.Color.Foreground=128,0,128
AbstractTextEditor.Color.SelectionBackground=0,128,0
currentLineColor=0,255,255 
AbstractTextEditor.Color.SelectionForeground.SystemDefault=false
AbstractTextEditor.Color.Background=250,250,250
AbstractTextEditor.Color.SelectionBackground.SystemDefault=false
eclipse.preferences.version=1
AbstractTextEditor.Color.SelectionForeground=21, 137, 255
```